# fade in for background-color(button) and drop down menu superfish menu

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, fadein, superfish

I use a modified drop down menu from superfish. 
I want to add a independent fade in effect for the drop down menu.
The background-color by mouseover and the drop down box should fade in slowly.

I added the menu on fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/g9usjkto/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/g9usjkto/2)

i tryed already:

```
 transition: background 1s;
-webkit-transition: background 1s;
-moz-transition: background 1s;
-o-transition: background 1s;
```

Thanks,
with best regards,
Danny77.

Comment: and where's the fiddle?

Comment: sorry i added now =)

Comment: Help me out please =). I added now some code, the drop down box is fade in now but only on second time.. look out new fiddle.

Comment: sorry but this not the way I make a dropdown menu, you're over-complicating it!

Comment: Do you know why my java code don´t work first time ? Only after second hover ?

Comment: probably because it's conflicting with the CSS animation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this submenu, it is highly and easily controllable, expandable and editable: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tc6owjdh/1/)**

```
$('#menu li').hover(function(){
    var i=$(this).index();
    var submenu=$('.submenu').eq(i);
    submenu.css({
        left:$(this).offset().left+'px',
        top:($(this).offset().top+$(this).outerHeight())+'px'
    }).stop().fadeIn(200);
},function(){
    var i=$(this).index();
    var submenu=$('.submenu').eq(i);
    submenu.stop().fadeOut(200);
});
$('.submenu').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().show();
},function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(200);
});
```

Comment: I have some problems =). I overworked your menu, but how i can add a list item without an unordered list ? And why the transition don´t work with the background color rgba ? http://jsfiddle.net/tc6owjdh/8/

Comment: An other problem =), if i zoom in or change the resolution the drop down box have a false offset.